# How to execute a stored procedure when changes done on grid view in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I am using a grid view dynamically based on users input of column count and there is a java script function also to be executed when changes are applied.
Text box is created init to enter data as below:

```
for (int i = 1; i < gvTable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                TextBox text = new TextBox();
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(text);

                text.Attributes["Type"] = "numbers";
                text.Attributes.Add("autocomplete", "off");
                text.Attributes.Add("on change", "Fun()");
                text.Attributes["type"] = "numbers";
            }
```

When any changes have done I have to exec the Stored procedure with those values.
I tried using buttons to exec procedure by onClick event but the text box are disappearing. Any suggestion on this to solve the problem.

Comment: can you please show your code on page Load event

Comment: On page Load no codes are there but on BindGridViewData the table gvTable has created  gvTable = new DataTable(); From there again grdView_RowDataBound is called where the TextBox logic is written.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this requirement.

Comment: the grid view assigned as bellow: there are totally 20 rows:

dataRow[0] = "Days";
            DataRow dataRow = gvTable.NewRow();
            DataRow dataRow1 = gvTable.NewRow();

dataRow[0] = "Days";
dataRow1[0] = "Amount";
                grdView1.DataSource = gvTable;
                grdView1.DataBind();
       with out using textbox, by using only gridview can I enter data and exec Procedure